# how to prevent duplicate form submission after user hits 'back' in browser in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cache-control

I don't want to prevent users from using the 'back' button, but if they do, I'd like to redirect them to the root url so that I don't get duplicate entries.

What I've tried so far has failed to work. I tried this in a before_action:

```
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
response.headers["Expires"] = "0"
```

And I've tried putting a hidden random string in my view:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :token, "#{SecureRandom.hex}" %>
```

...with this controller action:

```
def create
 token = params[:token]
 session[:tokens] ||= []
 if session[:tokens].include? token
   redirect_to root_path, notice: "That page is no longer viewable."
 else
  if @trade_wizard.trade.save
    session[:tokens] << token
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Success."
  else
    redirect_to({ action: Wizard::Trade::STEPS.first }, alert: 'There was a problem.')
  end
 end
end
```

The `token` in the above code gets added to `session[:tokens]` but the redirect does not occur when I hit back. Why? Furthermore, is this a bad idea? I foresee that sessions array filling up quickly.

Comment: The issue might be in your client browser (the page gets cached and is returned right away on back button). So you can't really handlethis in a controller

Comment: A bit unclear why hitten the back-button would cause duplicates? Can you explain your specific case in a little more detail? What are you trying to accomplish and how. I can deduce from your code you are building a multi-step form (wizard form?). Are you using a gem for this?

Comment: @nathanvda hitting the back button isn't what would cause duplicates, but essentially i don't want the user to be able to hit the `submit` button a second time. after they've submitted the form and left the final step in the wizard, i do not want them to be able to return to any of those steps. i couldn't find a gem to do what I wanted, so i wrote my own.

Comment: As a user, I would expect to be able to return on my steps and change stuff, up until the actual submit of the actual wizard. If that is not possible, maybe a single page form might be more suitable for you (you can even split it up in tabs to present like a wizard, but there will always be only one submit).

Comment: @nathanvda ya, that's exactly what i have. the wizard stores everything in a session variable, and then saves it to the database at the end. note that i say "after they've submitted the form and left the final step in the wizard." They can go back and change things BEFORE it's submitted, but i'd like to prevent the creation of duplicate records

Answer (score 3):

Handling this within the rails code may not work as the page may only be loaded from the browser cache when the user hits back. (May all be dependent on the users browser settings which may be over-riding the headers.)

Instead of trying to stop duplicate records being created by trying to prevent a action from being re-submitted. Could you add some uniqueness validation to the model to check at this point if the records has been saved before or not and return a validation error if it does?

You could even check the validation errors object in the controller and if one is present for the uniqueness validation, perform a redirect rather than the standard of re-rendering the form.

Comment: what do you mean by "uniqueness validation"? surely you don't mean `uniqueness: true`?